# Grails 3.3 execute H2 script command

Tags: grails, grails-orm, h2, grails-3.3

I'm running a small, trivial Grails 3.3.0 application using a H2 file based database. For simple backup reasons I would like to dump the current database state to a file using the H2 specific [SCRIPT](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script) command:

```
SCRIPT TO /path/to/backup/dir/tempoDb.sql;
```

Currently I am trying to execute the native SQL command like this.

```
User.withSession { session ->

   NativeSQLQuerySpecification nativeSQLQuerySpecification = new NativeSQLQuerySpecification("SCRIPT TO /path/to/backup/dir/tempoDb.sql;", null, null)

   session.executeNativeUpdate(nativeSQLQuerySpecification, new QueryParameters())
}
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can autowire the `dataSource` and try to run your sql query using the connection obtained from datasource Without going through Hibernate. The `dataSource` bean is registered in the Grails Spring context and it is an instance of `javax.sql.DataSource`.

Here is an example of a Grails service that backup the current H2 database to the file system.

```
@ReadOnly
class BackupService {

    DataSource dataSource

    def backup() {

        def sql = "SCRIPT DROP TO '${System.properties['java.io.tmpdir']}/backup.sql'"

        Statement statement = dataSource.connection.createStatement()
        boolean result = statement.execute(sql)
    }
}
```